# Python setup.py install uses wrong Python installation path

Tags: python, pythonpath

I'm on a bluehost-server which has a "rudimental" installation of python2.6.
I installed python2.6 in my user-directory which works fine so far, but when I try to install python packages with "setup.py install", "easy_install" or "pip install" I get:
`error: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/lib/python2.6/config/Makefile (No such file or directory)`
So, it tries to use the system-wide installation which does not have this Makefile. Also using the --prefix or --user argument doesn't help.

How can I tell pip or easy_install to use the python-installation in my user-directory?

Answer (score 5):

You need to execute `setup.py` by specifying which python interpreter on the command line, like this:

`/path/to/python setup.py install`

---

**UPDATE:**

The error message indicates that you don't have the `python-dev` package 
installed on your system.

Comment: I also tried that:
/home/user/.local/bin/python2.6 setup.py install --user
but still:
running install
error: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/lib/python2.6/config/Makefile (No such file or directory)

Comment: @AJ Yes, it isn't installed, but I'm not able to install it because it's just an account on a server. I was told to install python locally to have a "full" python installation, but my local installation still seems to refer to the system-wide "incomplete" installation.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem by installing the needed packages manually, meaning copying the sourcefiles into my local python folder.
Thanks for helping anyway.

Best
Jacques